# I'm facing error while installing pymrmr, any suggestion?

Tags: python

This is the error that I'm facing while installing pymrmr with the command -

```
pip install pymrmr

error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Buil 
dTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with 
exit status 2
```

Comment: the above suggestion doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the following error during install pymrmr

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wn37r25z\pymrmr_8299da47bb1249e8adefe32989c011b4\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wn37r25z\pymrmr_8299da47bb1249e8adefe32989c011b4\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-r71o_m6f\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Include\pymrmr' Check the logs for full command output.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4TsI.png)

Comment: If you have a question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score -1):

The pymrmr depends on numpy and Cython. You need to install the dependencies, then you should have no problem installing pymrmr:

```
pip install numpy Cython

pip install pymrmr
```

For more information, please go to https://pypi.org/project/pymrmr/